Unable to git push from Visual Studio, command line works?
So I got a git repository set up in Visual Studio. Commits etc work fine. It's seemingly able to pull from the repository fine (no errors, at least) but cannot push. I get an error about invalid remote name which doesn't make sense. Here's the output:
Pushing master
Invalid remote name "origin": invalid remote name: "F:\\<git_repo_path_on_disk>\\origin"
Error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<correct_repo_url>.git'
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: PushCommand.ExecutePushCommand
Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.

Here's the .git\config:
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"F:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" //t
    keepBackup = false
[merge]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[mergetool]
    prompt = true
[mergetool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"F:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\" //m
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = true
[lfs "https://github.com/<git url>/info/lfs"]
    access = basic
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/<git url>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

Pushing via command line seems to work fine. Git remote settings in Visual Studio seem fine. I assume I must have something misconfigured but can't figure out exactly what.

Can you include the content of your config file in the .git folder?

Added config above, thanks

The config seems file. Also confirmed by the fact that you can push from the command line. Maybe it's some VS configuration for Git. I've seen that there is a Git preferences section. Maybe there's something there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-settings?view=vs-2022#visual-studio-settings
